# unable to pass data from laravel 9 blade to vue 3 components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

when I tried in Vue 2 It worked but Vue 3 not working. Please help me.

```
<template>
    <p class="text-blue-600">The quick brown fox...</p>
            
      <div class="inline-flex justify-between w-full">
          <h1>{{ nodeGroups }} Hi</h1>
          
      </div>
     
</template>

<script >
export default{
    props:['nodeGroups'],

    mounted () {
      // Do something useful with the data in the template
      console.dir(this.nodeGroups)
    }
   
}

</script>
```

import { createApp } from "vue";

import Welcome from "./components/test.vue";

createApp(Welcome).mount("#app");

larvel blade

```
<div id="app">
            {{-- <node-group></node-group> --}}
            <Welcome :nodeGroups="'abc'"></Welcome>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please share your app.js file code

Comment: import { createApp } from "vue";

import Welcome from "./components/test.vue";

createApp(Welcome).mount("#app");

Comment: Have you tried to set up your app with Inertia and vite?

Comment: I haven't. Do you think those are necessary?

Comment: and not possible without them?

Comment: They're not actually necessary but it will help you get rid of so much boilerplate + Inertia will help you with your links and posting data through AJAX automatically with so many benefits without needing to use axios every time. You'll only use Axios when you need to make API calls or fetch data that you won't need the page to be refreshed to reflect data. You would use Inertia to navigate between pages using something like <Link :href="route('admin.dashboard')>Dashboard</Link> instead of using VueRouter which keeps you in the Laravel ecosystem

Comment: And as for Vite, it is really super fast and much better than WebPack. If you need help with setting Laravel with Inertia and Vite, let me know